# Control audio tag via react state

Tags: reactjs

I have this code at my react component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      audioContainer: document.getElementById('audio'),
    });
  }
```

And when needed I run some action:

```
this.state.audioContainer.start()
```

I think that this is not the best option to do that.

Following the solution above I did this:

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

```
class AudioControl extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.start) {
      this.start();
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ start }) {
    if (start !== this.props.start && start === true) {
      this.start();
    }
  }

  start() {
    this._audio.start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <audio ref={a => this._audio = a}>
        <source src="url" type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio>
    );
  }
}

AudioControl.defaultProps = {
  start: false,
};

AudioControl.propTypes = {
  start: PropTypes.bool,
};


export default AudioControl;
```

I imported at Parent Component:

```
<AudioControl start />
```

I and got this error:
Dynamic page loading failed TypeError: this._audio.start is not a function

Comment: The question should be why is it in state in the first place. Does it need to be?

Comment: Yes, I wanna know if there are something like <audio this.state.someVar /> at render

Comment: You may use REF for your audio-component (in the render() method), then you may control it in proper react-way. If you could show more code, your whole component, especially how you render that Audio component, then I may give you some clearer example, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not recommended to use the state to keep references to DOM elements. Use React [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead, with an instance variable.

```
class AudioControl extends React.Component{

  start(){
    this._audio.play()
  }

  render(){
    return (
      //..
      <audio ref={(a) => this._audio = a} />
      //..
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems  nice, I gonna try :)

Comment: This is the right way, with using REF, as I commented under the above question (I didn't see your answer at first)

Comment: I tried this solution and I got an error. I edit my post, can you check for me?

Comment: I got it, changing start for play